# Parameterized Array Not Working In All Cases

Tags: powershell-3.0

Had a hard time thinking of a really good title for this. Mods please feel free to edit it if you can think of a better title.

Powershell 3.

Here's a sample function:

```
Function New-Cmdlet
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)]
    Param([Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$True,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
                [String[]]$ComputerName)
    BEGIN
    {            
        Write-Verbose -Message "Cmdlet is starting."
    }
    PROCESS
    {            
        Write-Verbose -Message "Beginning Process block on $ComputerName"
    }
    END
    {
        Write-Verbose -Message "Running End block."
    }
}
```

Now if I run `Get-Content C:\hosts.txt | New-Cmdlet`, the PROCESS block is run once for each entry found in hosts.txt. Which is good and correct.

If I run `"host1","host2" | New-Cmdlet`, then the PROCESS block is run twice; once for host1 and again for host2.  Again, that is good and correct.

But if I run `New-Cmdlet -ComputerName "host1","host2"` or just about any other variant I can think of like `New-Cmdlet -ComputerName @("host1","host2")` ... the PROCESS block is only run **once.**  Which is bad.

Any idea what I can do to make this work properly in each scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ComputerName is an array.

New-Cmdlet -ComputerName "host1","host2" - this passes in ONE array - your code is executed once and returns

You should modify your code to loop through $computerName inside your code

Comment: Thanks. I guess I was just confused because the Process block behaves as its own foreach loop when I use the pipeline, so adding a foreach loop inside it seemed redundant.

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same question on the TechNet forums a couple of years ago.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/fc0bf987-a4f2-4ebb-9ff3-8c4acef346ed/process-pipeline-input-and-parameter-input-the-same-way

I wanted the same behaviour as the -Path parameter in Copy-Item

Copy-item -Path "File.txt", "File2.txt" -Destination "D:\"

"File.txt", "File2.txt" | Copy-item -Destination "D:\"

Like you say... when content is received from the pipeline we have to loop an already scalar value which is redundant. Like this...

```
Function DoStuff {

    Param (   
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True)][string[]]$Item
    )

    Process {
        $Item | ForEach-Object {
            # Do the stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

I've just looked att Microsofts Copy-Item CmdLet in JustDecompile, to see how Microsoft did it. They do it the same way... the Path-parameter is an array that they loop in their ProcessRecord-implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question on the TechNet forums a couple of years ago.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/fc0bf987-a4f2-4ebb-9ff3-8c4acef346ed/process-pipeline-input-and-parameter-input-the-same-way

Like you say... when content is received from the pipeline we have to loop an already scalar value which is redundant.

Comment: tell us the complete solution here, do not only link to an external resource.